# How can I insert a lot of records into database all at once from a textarea where every line of it is a record?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm running a website aimed for medical students, I have a profile and points for every student in my database, So when they participate in an activity I must add X amount of points for all the participants, and I do this manually using an ajax form, How can I run a MySQL query to give X amount of points for each student in a large text input (textarea)? So I can insert the points all at once which is much easier and faster, Here is an example:

```
21910431|1|Participant
22010431|3|Subleader
21810531|6|Headleader
(Student ID)|(points)|(role in activity)
```

So when I fill the textarea with the data above it must insert 3 records into the `activity_log` table.
How can I insert this into the database all at once? Like this:

```
$query= "INSERT INTO `activity_log` (`Student ID`, `points`, `role`) VALUES (ALL THE VALUES IN THE EXAMPLE ABOVE)";
```

**If anyone can help can you write the code to show me how? Thanks alot!**

Comment: The syntax is: `VALUES (data for row 1), (data for row 2), ...`. Use a loop to add this form to your query.

Comment: Explode on new line, then explode on pipe. Iterate over new line explosion for row data, then pipe for column values. Parameterize query.

Comment: Since you should also use prepared statements, it's easiest if you use PDO. You can put `?` placeholders in the query, and then put all the values as an array in the `execute()` call.

Comment: @Barmar why a loop?

Comment: @ysth Or put all all the values in an array and use `implode()`.

Comment: Rough idea, https://3v4l.org/Y4CTu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using PDO:

```
$lines = explode("\n", $_POST['textarea']); // split into lines
$params = [];
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if ($line) {  // skip blank lines
        $params += explode('|', $line); // split each line into individual values
    }
}
# Make all the (?, ?, ?) that go after VALUES
$values = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($params)/3, '(?, ?, ?)')); 
$query= "INSERT INTO `activity_log` (`Student ID`, `points`, `role`) VALUES $values";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute($params);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can insert multiple rows:

```
INSERT INTO `activity_log` (`Student ID`, `points`, `role`) VALUES (21910431,1,'Participant'),(22010431,3,'Subleader'),...;
```

Using placeholders, this would be:

```
INSERT INTO `activity_log` (?,?,?),(?,?,?),...;
```

just passing all the values to execute.

Comment: Can you please write a code that passes the values into the query? and it might reach like 100-150 values, is that OK?

Comment: looks like Barmar did.  the total query has to be less than the server @@max_allowed_packet setting, but that's usually at least a megabyte